# How to remove wordpress date?

Tags: wordpress

I have a site here: http://www.alfandegas.gv.ao/wordpress/

When you load the site, the date appears. I have scanned the code and can't see any mention of date anywhere.

Can someone please advise what to do?

Header.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * @package Betheme
 * @author Muffin group
 * @link http://muffingroup.com
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<?php echo date('l jS F Y'); ?>
<?php 
    if( $_GET && key_exists('mfn-rtl', $_GET) ):
        echo '<html class="no-js" lang="ar" dir="rtl">';
    else:
?>
<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- head -->
<head>

<!-- meta -->
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<?php if( mfn_opts_get('responsive') ) echo '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">'; ?>

<title><?php
if( mfn_title() ){
    echo mfn_title();
} else {
    global $page, $paged;
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    bloginfo( 'name' );
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'betheme' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
}
?></title>

<?php do_action('wp_seo'); ?>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php mfn_opts_show('favicon-img',THEME_URI .'/images/favicon.ico'); ?>" type="image/x-icon" /> 

<!-- wp_head() -->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<!-- body -->
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <?php get_template_part( 'includes/header', 'sliding-area' ); ?>

    <?php if( mfn_header_style() == 'header-creative' ) get_template_part( 'includes/header', 'creative' ); ?>

    <!-- #Wrapper -->
    <div id="Wrapper">

        <?php 
            // Header Featured Image -----------
            $header_style = false;
            if( mfn_ID() && ! is_search() ){
                if( ( ( mfn_ID() == get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) || ( get_post_type() == 'page' ) ) && has_post_thumbnail( mfn_ID() ) ){
                    $subheader_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( mfn_ID() ), 'full' );
                    $header_style = 'style="background-image:url('. $subheader_image[0] .');"';
                }
            }
        ?>

        <?php if( mfn_header_style() == 'header-below' ) echo mfn_slider(); ?>

        <!-- #Header_bg -->
        <div id="Header_wrapper" <?php echo $header_style; ?>>

            <!-- #Header -->
            <header id="Header">
                <?php if( mfn_header_style() != 'header-creative' ) get_template_part( 'includes/header', 'top-area' ); ?>  
                <?php if( mfn_header_style() != 'header-below' ) echo mfn_slider(); ?>
            </header>

            <?php 
                if( is_search() ){

                    // Page title -------------------------
                    echo '<div id="Subheader">';
                        echo '<div class="container">';
                            echo '<div class="column one">';

                                global $wp_query;
                                $total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
                                echo '<h1 class="title">'. $total_results .' '. __('results found for:','betheme') .' '. get_search_query() .'</h1>';

                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';

                } elseif( ! is_front_page() && ! mfn_slider() ){

                    // Page title -------------------------
                    echo '<div id="Subheader">';
                        echo '<div class="container">';
                            echo '<div class="column one">';

                                // Title
                                echo '<h1 class="title">'. mfn_page_title() .'</h1>';

                                // Breadcrumbs
                                if( mfn_opts_get('show-breadcrumbs') ) mfn_breadcrumbs();

                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';

                }
            ?>

        </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your header PHP code? It may also be in your theme's functions, or another file. There are really too many options.

Comment: @mevius Please see the header.php code above. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove line 10.

`<?php echo date('l jS F Y'); ?>`

Comment: Thank you!! I had look at it so many times, I just could not see it! Haha thanks